# Postgresql + sqlalchemy: raise Empty sqlalchemy.util.queue.Empty

Tags: python

Do you know why the code below is getting all the errors that appear in the traceback below? The code is to read the data from a table, if dont exist the table is created and the data is loaded in the postgresql table, but its not working. Do you know why? The version of python is 3.6 I dont know if can be something related to that.

python:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, MetaData
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, request

engine = create_engine('postgresql:///test')
source_table_name = 'data'
song_aux_table_name = 'song_aux_matrix'
song_table_name = 'songr'


def init():
    global insert, source_table, source_df, song_df, song_similarity_matrix
    meta = MetaData()
    try:
        source_df = pd.read_sql_table(source_table_name, engine, index_col='index')
    except ValueError as e:
        print('SLoading from CSV, writing to DB.')
        source_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
        source_df.columns = [c.lower() for c in source_df.columns]
        source_df.to_sql(source_table_name, engine)
        print('Wrote to DB.')
    source_table = Table(source_table_name, meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
    insert = source_table.insert().values()
    try:
        song_similarity_matrix = pd.read_sql_table(song_aux_table_name, engine, index_col='index')
        song__df = pd.read_sql_table(song_table_name, engine, index_col='index')
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)


init()
```

Tracebak:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1122, in _do_get
    return self._pool.get(wait, self._timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\queue.py", line 145, in get
    raise Empty
sqlalchemy.util.queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2147, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 328, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 766, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 516, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1138, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1135, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 333, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 461, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 651, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 105, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 393, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 38, in <module>
    init()
  File "app.py", line 23, in init
    source_df = pd.read_sql_table(source_table_name, engine, index_col='index')
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 258, in read_sql_table
    meta.reflect(only=[table_name], views=True)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 3855, in reflect
    with bind.connect() as conn:
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2091, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 90, in __init__
    if connection is not None else engine.raw_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2177, in raw_connection
    self.pool.unique_connection, _connection)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2151, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1465, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    exc_info
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 186, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2147, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 328, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 766, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 516, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1138, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1135, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 333, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 461, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 651, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 105, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 393, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) fe_sendauth: no password supplied


(env) C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj>python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1122, in _do_get
    return self._pool.get(wait, self._timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\queue.py", line 145, in get
    raise Empty
sqlalchemy.util.queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2147, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 328, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 766, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 516, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1138, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1135, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 333, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 461, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 651, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 105, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 393, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 32, in <module>
    init()
  File "app.py", line 16, in init
    source_df = pd.read_sql_table(source_table_name, engine, index_col='index')
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 258, in read_sql_table
    meta.reflect(only=[table_name], views=True)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 3855, in reflect
    with bind.connect() as conn:
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2091, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 90, in __init__
    if connection is not None else engine.raw_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2177, in raw_connection
    self.pool.unique_connection, _connection)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2151, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1465, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    exc_info
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 186, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2147, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 328, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 766, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 516, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1138, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1135, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 333, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 461, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 651, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 105, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 393, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\testproj\env\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Comment: have you tried to provide a password ?

Comment: Same issue with: create_engine('postgresql://root:pass@localhost/testdb')